# How to sort through a yaml file and provide values for each tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I am working on a script to read through a YAML config and am having some problems with the logic with the for loops and dictionary. I can get it to print each value when done static, but this throws off the purpose of my script.  As I would like to dynamically call functions using the YAML config file.

So far I can only get the first key and value from my for script.  Anytime I try to go further by using dataMap[key][0][value] I cannot go further then 1.

```py
import yaml

with open('design.yaml') as f:
    dataMap = yaml.safe_load(f)
print("================================")
print("Topo #1")
print("================================")
print(f"Topo Name: {dataMap['topology'][0]['name']}")
print(f"vPort: {dataMap['topology'][0]['vport']}")
print(f"DG Name: {dataMap['topology'][1]['devicegroup']}")
print(f"Multiplier: {dataMap['topology'][1]['multiplier']}")
print(f"Eth Name: {dataMap['topology'][1]['eth']['name']}")
print("Auto Output - To look just like above")
print("================================")
for key, value in dataMap.items():
    #Updated
    print("KEY: {} - VALUE: {}".format(key, value[0].items()))
    print("====")
print("================================")
#print("Recursive Function Test")
#print("================================")
#myprint(dataMap)
```

```
config:
 -name: Test
topology:
 - name: DC1
   vport: Port1
 - devicegroup: DC1 DG1
   multiplier: 50
   eth:
     name: ETH1
     macStart: 00:01:01:01:00:01
     macStep: 00:00:00:00:00:01
     enableVLAN: True
     vlanID: 100
     vlanStep: 0
   ipv4:
     name: DC1 DG1 IPv4
     startIP: 10.1.1.10
     stepIP: 0.0.0.1
     netmask: 255.255.255.0
     gateway: 10.1.1.1
     gwStep: 0.0.0.0
 - name: TEST2
   vport: Port2
 - devicegroup: TEST DG2
```

```
Output:
KEY: config - VALUE: dict_items([('apiServer', '10.255.251.105'), ('apiServerPort', 443), ('osPlatform', 'linux'), ('username', 'admin'), ('password', 'admin'), ('chassisIP', '10.253.0.82'), ('licenseserver', '10.253.0.82'), ('licensemode', 'subscription'), ('licensetier', 'tier3'), ('POCName', 'XXXXX'), ('POCNumber', 'XXXXX')])
====
KEY: topology - VALUE: dict_items([('name', 'DC1'), ('vport', 'Port1')])
```

My problem is now, how do I pull in the devicegroup information from the YAML file?  Changing value[0] to value[1] causes an index issue.

```
print("KEY: {} - VALUE: {}".format(key, value[1].items()))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So how do I step further into the YAML file with this?

Comment: Please make a minimal code example that reproduces your issue, and make sure your post is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but I don't think a function call within an f-string is evaluated, so try and do:

```
    print("KEY: {} - VALUE: {}".format(key, value[0].items()))
```

instead.

Additionally the value for the `key` config is a sequence (i.e. loaded as a Python list) that has only **one** element, so you cannot index further in that sequence then `0`.

You'd better try and do something like:

```
for key, values in dataMap.items():
    for idx, value in enumerate(values):
        print("KEY: {} - VALUE[{}]: {}".format(key, idx, value.items()))
        print("====")
```

Comment: Thank you.. It works but not exactly what I am looking for.. Updated my above post to show the new output.

Comment: "above" functions only as a preposition or an adverb, neither of which can take the determiner "my". The same holds for "below" and the definite article "the". So please use  "my post above" resp. "the suggestion below".

Comment: That did what i was looking for!  Thank you for the assistance.